# forcing dtype upon read_table in pandas -- get NAs for misformatted records, don't break

Tags: python, pandas, types

I am trying to specify data type upon reading in data with `pandas.read_table`. My main reason is not speed, but to ignore misformatted records, which unfortunately occur. But instead of populating such records with NAs, the script simply breaks, and I found no other switch of [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) that would turn forcing on.

This is on pandas 0.17.1

What is there to do?

The relevant line is in the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/Downloads/mock_monthly_inpatient_treatments.py", line 31, in <module>
    treatments = pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[0,3,4,6], engine='c', dtype={'LopNr':np.uint16,'INDATUMA':np.uint16,'UTDATUMA':np.uint16,'DIAGNOS':object})
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 498, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 285, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 747, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1197, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 766, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 788, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 865, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9261)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 972, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:10654)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1053, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas/parser.c:12010)
ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of <u2 for object dtyped data in column 3
```

The misformatted data in column 3 is `2008o730` here.

Comment: does `error_bad_lines=False` work?

Comment: No, it does not. I.e. the run still breaks on the line with the non-confirming field.

Comment: it may not be fast, but there is a way to pass your own conversion function in for each field, iirc.

Comment: Speaking of lame workarounds, even `all_treatments['INDATUMA'] = all_treatments['INDATUMA'].astype('int',raise_on_error=False)` breaks with `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: well, i was suggesting writing your own conversion function that would return an `np.uint16` if it works, and `np.NaN` if it doesn't.